# Overly Complicated Git w/Mega-Project & Nested Repos

Tags: git, version-control, repository, git-submodules, git-subtree

I'm working on a large project with many sub-components all related to one another and referencing each other. The directory structure looks something like this, with each bullet being a directory, and dependencies for the contents of a given directory being parenthetically notated.

[image: Directory Structure.]

To keep everybody on the same page, I need this whole structure to be a (super)repo with the following requirements. I would like for each sub-directory to be its own repository, or at least such that running *git log* run in *./docs* shows only the git commits related to *./docs*; the goal is to allow work to be more easily compartmentalized so that I can type *git log* when I or another coworker is working in *./src/fw/base-library* and not mentally have to sort through commits related to *./docs/doc-template*, and I don't want to type *git log ./src/fw/base-library*. More or less, each directory is its own repo with its own submodule/subtree dependencies.

As for the directories that are dependent on one another, e.g., *./src/sw/driver-linux* being dependent on *./src./sw/driver-shared* and *./brd/docs/design-notes* being dependent on *./docs/doc-template*, I intend for these to be submodules (not subtrees), as I have no real need to edit the dependency code outside of its own directory. In other words, I really only need each sub-rep, e.g., *./brd/docs/trade-off_explanation*, to point towards a "working" commit of its dependency, e.g., *./docs/doc-template*, but not actually contain a copy of the source code I could edit and then push upstream, e.g., to *./docs/doc-template*.

I'm having trouble understanding if what I want is possible with git.

1. *git clone [super-project]* needs to clone the entire super-project structure from the remote. How should the sub-repos, e.g., *./docs/design-notes* be integrated into the super-project repo to do this? It doesn't seem to make sense that they would be simply submodules or subtrees, as they would have to be pointing to the "real" repos on a remote, which would necessitate duplication of directory structure in order to maintain the super-project structure, correct?
2. Is what I'm wanting with true sub-repos and *git log* (instead of something like *git log ./src/sw/brd-test*) even possible?
3. The 10,000 ft. view: am I grossly overcomplicating the sharing and syncing of project files among myself and my co-workers.

Comment: If you have submodules, you have to be inside of the submodule directory in order for `git log` to only show you that submodule's log. If it were a single repo, while in that directory, you'd have to just type `git log .` instead. Or, if you're down a directory, and want to see commits from the root of the would-be submodule folder, perhaps you'd need: `git log ../` which seems like a pretty small inconvenience compared to the overhead of submodules.

Comment: Perhaps using aliases to view the log of your desired directories would help get you closer, then you could run the alias from anywhere in the entire repo.

Comment: We use Google's repo tool to manage a codebase composed of hundreds of repositories. The pro is it works quite well and the con is the users have to learn how to use it. https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/.